# Python OpenAI Whisper FileNotFoundError when running a standalone created with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, openai-whisper

I made a small Python program that uses [OpenAI whisper's library](https://github.com/openai/whisper). Everything works fine in my virtual environment.

I generated a `.exe` of the whole thing with [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/), but when I run the resulting file, I get the following error:

```
Exception ignored in thread started by: <function start_interpretor at 0x000001F9EC80F430>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interpretor.py", line 67, in start_interpretor
  File "transcriber.py", line 125, in run_transcription
  File "transcriber.py", line 88, in progress_transcription
  File "whisper\transcribe.py", line 121, in transcribe
  File "whisper\audio.py", line 141, in log_mel_spectrogram
  File "whisper\audio.py", line 94, in mel_filters
  File "numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 405, in load
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Div-o\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI236562\\whisper\\assets\\mel_filters.npz'
```

I have tried to add the datas object to the `.spec` file generated by PyInstaller:

```
a = Analysis(
//...
datas=[('.venv/Lib/site-packages/whisper/assets/mel_filters.npz', '.venv/Lib/site-packages/whisper/assets'),],
//...
)
```

I even added `recursive_copy_metadata="whisper"` to the `EXE()` in the same file, but the issue persists.

Any idea what is causing that?

Comment: please create a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using `faster-whisper`.

Also your datas should probably look like this:

```
a = Analysis(
//...
datas=[('.venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\whisper\\assets\\mel_filters.npz', '\\whisper\\assets'),],
//...
)
```

Comment: It works perfectly, and is indeed faster than a whisper. Thank you! Regarding the data formatting, that didn't change anything...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when I was trying to build my python program using py2exe. Since I was using `--onedir` I was able to look into files that were bundeled to the build and noticed that mel_filters.npz was actually there but was located in the root folder. The fix that worked for me was to include the whole whisper folder from my .venv in my `--add-data` parameter so that the program could find the file from a correct directory.

Pyinstaller command that py2exe generated and worked for me:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --add-data "project_location/.venv/Lib/site-packages/whisper;whisper/"  "project_location/main.py"
```